# building using multiple machines

Tags: c++, distributed, building

I have a huge Windows C++ project that takes a lot of time to be compiled. Do you know if there is some FREE tool being able to build using multiple pc connected together?

Do you know if there is some free tool doing the same in Linux using GCC?

At least there is something that I can do to split the work myself?
Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting as well to hear about commercial tools.

Answer (score 2):

I am long time user of commercial IncrediBuild. Happy with it so far. What I like most it its sandbox implementation - no need to install anything on agent machines, both source and tool-chain synchronization is handled transparently for you.

When we started to use it few years ago, there were no other tools for C++ Windows development for distributed builds. I did not look for any such tool recently, therefore there might be some competition for it already.

One important "competion" is ability of Visual Studio since 2008 to use multiple cores for builds - this is "free" as long as you already own Visual Studio.

Comment: Add another happy user for IncrediBuild. In a C++ project I worked on it took the times for a full build down from 60mins to 12mins. When you're doing template stuff (all headers) in a multi-MLoC project, this is a life safer. It's not really cheap, but it's worth every cent you pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TeamCity Professional Edition ( http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/ ) which is free for up to 3 clients. ( http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp )

Comment: Is this .NET only, or it can build native C++ as well?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Have a look at the following link: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/274415